# Cannot npm install after cloned repo

Tags: node.js, reactjs, github, npm

Good evening,

after browsing for solutions myself during my Software Dev course in the past 4 months (newbie here and graduated last week as a Jr Software Dev) I am finding myself asking a question and hoping for help. I've searched around but could not find anything related.

For some reason I had to remove my classnotes/lab/project files from the Macbook I had been borrowing during my time at CodeClan. I also npxkilled 13GB of node_modules prior because I almost ran out of space.

Yesterday evening I wanted to git clone my portfolio (React App) and continue working on it.
The usual git clone into new directory, then cd into the working directory, npm init -y and then npm install which failed already. A json.package or jason-lock.package was there. I got npm err 404 is not in the npm registry, which led me to set the registry and used my GitHub repo url for that (which is also a .io github page). Npm install would then tell me everything is up to date. Node modules weren't there at all, I removed both json packages and tried to npm install again, which usually works. I also used the npm cache clean / verify which did not do anything.

I then closed everything, went out of my working directory and updated node and npm.
I updated node from 17.9 to 18.3 and npm from 8.8 to 8.11, restarted Mac again.

Via terminal created completely new directory for a Sandbox react app, cd into that and tried to npx create-react-app play-ground - not even that is working. It now comes back with following error messages, which is weird. It looks as if a completely new react app, which has nothing to do with my portfolio still wants to connect with that repo.

I removed the whole portfolio repo from this Mac and there should not even be a trace of it.

I hope I've explained my issues well enough. Instructors are not around anymore, lol and my partner who is also a Dev is a bit clueless as well. I appreciate any help and please bear in mind that I am a noob, still trying to read error messages and trying to solve them myself. However, I have been dealing with this react app issue since yesterday evening and I am running out of ideas.

Thanks a lot !!

````
➜  Sandbox la
total 0
➜  Sandbox npx create-react-app play-ground
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://annikaneumann.github.io/portfolio-annika/create-react-app
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'create-react-app@latest' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/annikaneumann/.npm/_logs/2022-06-14T17_02_55_107Z-debug-0.log
➜  Sandbox ```
````

Answer (score 0):

> which led me to set the registry and used my GitHub repo url for that

That's most likely the problem, it means that `npm` will now use your Github repo as its main package repository, which it obviously isn't.

You should reset it so it points to the official NPM repository again:

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

(I don't know if this will also solve your initial 404 error, but you'd have to provide more information on that if you want it solved)

Comment: Thank you, that helped me being able to create a new react app.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, that helped me creating a new react app. I did try to git clone and npm install my portfolio another time with a new working folder, but it would come back again with following error message. Both json packages are there but I can't install the node modules, no matter if I use the npm config set registry or not.

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://annikaneumann.github.io/portfolio-annika
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'homepage@https://AnnikaNeumann.github.io/portfolio-annika' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/annikaneumann/.npm/_logs/2022-06-14T18_44_36_110Z-debug-0.log
➜  annikaneumann.github.io git:(main) npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
➜  annikaneumann.github.io git:(main) code . 
➜  annikaneumann.github.io git:(main) npm start

> portfolio_annika@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

sh: react-scripts: command not found
➜  annikaneumann.github.io git:(main) npm install
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://annikaneumann.github.io/portfolio-annika
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'homepage@https://AnnikaNeumann.github.io/portfolio-annika' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/annikaneumann/.npm/_logs/2022-06-14T18_48_21_895Z-debug-0.log
➜  annikaneumann.github.io git:(main)
```

Comment: Please don't reply to other answers with your own answer. You can use comments instead :)